# Get key from HashMap in Android by position or index

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> CHILD_NAME_DOB = new HashMap<>();
```

Suppose the values in `CHILD_NAME_DOB` are:

```
<adam,15121990>
<roy,01051995>
<neha,05091992>
<alisha,11051992>
```

I am trying to fetch the last key element from `CHILD_NAME_DOB`. That is, I want to fetch key `alisha` from the example above to temporary `String name`.

Also I want to know on how to fetch data by index.

Eg.: if `int index = 2` , I want key `"Neha"` in `String name`

TIA.

Edit: DateOfBirth value (value data in `CHILD_NAME_DOB`) is dynamic and is unknown. So [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112975/get-key-from-a-hashmap-using-the-value) is not what I want.

Comment: `HashMaps` don't have indexes. Possibly what you're looking for is `LinkedHashMap`, although it's anybody's guess.

Comment: @EJP, Yeah, my bad. I think, I should go for `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Hey guys, how about if I do like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3422405/2798218).  Use an `interator` but declare the the `String key` and `value `outside the  `iterator`. This way I'll get the last key element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Pentium10 for [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422405/2798218)
And I little modified it according to my need.

```
String key="default";
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = CHILD_NAME_DOB.keySet().iterator();
while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
     key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
     //String value=(String)meMap.get(key);
     }
Toast.makeText(viewEnterChildExp.getContext(), "Key: "+key , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I'm getting the last key element by this.

I'll update as soon I also get to find an easy way to key by index.

Comment: This will *not* work reliably for HashMap. You need to use LinkedHashMap as I've stated in my answer.

Comment: At first `HashMap` worked. But later, after some random testing, it returned unexpected results.   Then I tried `LinkedHashMap` and it worked well with my random testing too. So at the end, I went with `LinkedHashMap` . Thank You @aioobe.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Java 8?

Answer (score 7):

**Single line solution:**

First note that the Java `HashMap` does not guarantee the order of entries. So each time you iterate over a HashMap, entries appear in different positions. You will need `LinkedHashMap` that guarantees the predictable iteration order.

```
Map<String, String> CHILD_NAME_DOB = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Get the key by index:

```
key = (new ArrayList<>(CHILD_NAME_DOB.keySet())).get(index)
```

Get the value by index:

```
CHILD_NAME_DOB.get(key)
```

Comment: after lot's of R&D get answer

Answer (score 4):

This way to get key....

```
public static String getHashMapKeyFromIndex(HashMap hashMap, int index){

    String key = null;
    HashMap <String,Object> hs = hashMap;
    int pos=0;
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : hs.entrySet())
    {
        if(index==pos){
            key=entry.getKey();
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return key;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an ArrayMap instead of a HashMap. To get the value by index use:

```
ArrayMap.valueAt(index);
```

To get the Key at an index use:

```
ArrayMap.keyAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching the "last" key and fetch by index is not supported by `HashMap`. You can use a `LinkedHashMap` and lookup the element with index 2 (or the last element) by iterating over it. But this will be a O(n) operation.

I suggest you use a `List<Pair<String, String>>` if the order of the keys/values is important to you and you wish to do index based lookup.

If both key based and index based lookup is important to you, you could use a combined data structure that consists of both a `List` and a `HashMap`, but note that removal of elements will be `O(n)`.

Comment: hmm. Maybe you're right. Lemme also wait and see for other answers

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class Child

```
public class Child(){
private String name;
private String number;

....

}
```

and then put this object in a List

```
public static List<Child> CHILD_NAME_DOB = new ArrayList<Child>(); // using LinkedList would defeat the purpose
```

in this way you can invoke the method `get(int index)`, that returns the element at the specified position in this list.

In your example

```
<adam,15121990>
<roy,01051995>
<neha,05091992>
<alisha,11051992>
```

invoking `CHILD_NAME_DOB.get(2)` you'll get `<neha,05091992>`(as Child object)

Comment: Why then `LinkedList` if you access the index?

Comment: This will of course loose all benefits associated with a map, such as key based lookup in O(1).

Comment: How can he access a "row" by index in O(1) ? Map has not the concept of indexing.

Comment: the value obtained by the hash code and all hashmap indexed

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` does not have a concept of ordering, so getting the n-th entry does not make sense. You could use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead, which is ordered on its keys.

However, you should reconsider your model as you seem to have conflicting interests. On the one hand, accessing by index is typical for `Lists`, whereas accessing by key is typical for `Maps`. I'm not sure in which situation you'd want to do both.

If you really want to do both index and key accessing, you could write your own data structure that stores the data in a list combined with a mapping from key to index and vice versa. I would recommend against this, but if that's really what you want, then I think that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the best solution, but what about this solution (pseudocode!). Just combine List and Map in one class.

```
public class UserBirthday {

    private List<String>        names          = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, String> CHILD_NAME_DOB = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void add(String name, String bd) {

        if (!CHILD_NAME_DOB.containsKey(name)) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        CHILD_NAME_DOB.put(name, bd);

    }

    public String getByName(String name) {
        return CHILD_NAME_DOB.get(name);
    }

    public String getByIndex(int index) {
        return getByName(names.get(index)); // TODO: range test
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserBirthday ub = new UserBirthday();
        ub.add("dit", "12345678");
        ub.add("lea", "234239423");
        ub.add("alex", "43534534");
        ub.add("ted", "099098790");

        System.out.println(ub.getByIndex(2));
        System.out.println(ub.getByName("alex"));
    }

}
```

You may get some problems if you remove an entry, but it should be just a suggestion.

Comment: IMO this is "syntactic sugar". When you invoke `getByIndex(int index)` you also invoke `names.get(index)`, that takes O(n) anyway. Thus, what is the difference with my answer?

Comment: @FabrizioMorello what do you mean with "names.get(index) takes O(n)" ?

Comment: `names` is a `List`. When you invoke `getByIndex(int index)`, this method in turn invokes `names.get(index)`. The `get` method of `List` has O(n) complexity.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello no. get method of ArrayList has O(1). this is basics... Look at source code or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182597/time-complexity-for-java-arraylist

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're absolutely right. My mistake ! But my answer is anyway the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (String key : hmList.keySet()) {
        String value = hmList.get(key);

        Log.e("HashMap values", "key=" + key + " ,value=" + value);
    }
```